# Find and mass copy

Tags: find, cp

I have a script on macOS that will find files ending in .csv extension; then I am copying these files with a forced backup. However, the bash compiler complains

```
find -E . -regex './.*csv' -type f -wholename '.*' -exec cp -f -r {} {} \;
```

For example, I get this output:

```
cp: ./banknotes.csv and ./banknotes.csv are identical (not copied).
cp: ./crabs.csv and ./crabs.csv are identical (not copied).
cp: ./dogmandibles.csv and ./dogmandibles.csv are identical (not copied).
cp: ./winequality-white-3.csv and ./winequality-white-3.csv are identical (not copied).
...
```

And none of these files copy. The objective is to find files with `.csv` extension then execute a copy of these files in the same directory. Therefore, I have duplicate files.

UPDATE:

For example, If I wanted to append an increasing positive integer of values by enumeration of found files:

```
find . -name '*.csv'| while ((i++)); read lines; do echo $lines | sed -E "s|[^\.]*$|$i.csv|g" | xargs -I{} cp $lines {} ; done
```

Whereas, If I wanted to append a specific number:

```
find . -name '*.csv'| while read lines; do sed -E "s|[^\.]*$|2.csv|g" | xargs -I{} cp $lines {}  ; done
```

The first will do the following on file outputs:

```
file_x.csv
file_y.csv
file_x.1.csv
file_y.2.csv
```

Whereas the second option will do the following:

```
file_x.csv
file_y.csv
file_x.2.csv
file_y.2.csv
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? `cp file file` makes no sense, that's what you do here

Comment: That's not Bash complaining, that's the `cp` command. Also Bash is not a compiler, but an interpreter of the shell language (its own dialect), and a program providing a command-line interface.

Comment: Yes, please explain what files you want to find. Your `find` command makes no sense. If you just want files with the csv extension, all you need is `find . -name '*.csv'`. And what operating system are you using? What `find` has an `-E` option and also supports `-wholename`? In any case, the `-wholename '.*'` is pointless since that just matches everything. Please [edit] your question, explain what you are trying to do more clearly and where you want files to be copied and we can help you find a better way.

Comment: @terdon The find works perfectly well on my system; My operating system is the following: `Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0`, essentially, I have no issues with `find`, it prints out the expected files. I thought `cp` would copy a file like when I right-click on a file and press copy, it inserts a new copy of the file. That was my expectation. Because, I wanted to learn how to mass copy so file names are changed, then create new ideas to mass modify files. It's all for experience and knowledge gain, and exercises.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do. I know the `find` seems to work, I am just saying that it is needlessly complicated and you can replace all of `find -E . -regex './.*csv' -type f -wholename '.*'` with just `find . -name '*.csv'`. Also, your current command would fine a file named `thisisnotacsv`, because you are searching for file names ending in `csv` and not `.csv`, since in regular expressions, `.` means "any character". But never mind all that, please explain what you want because we can't help you if you don't: where do you want to copy to?

Comment: @terdon You might have mixed up the regex expression, I instead did `'./.*csv'` so it specifically only grabs those with a `.csv` extension. I have tested this to make sure to clear your doubts. Good question! For now, I wanted to copy into my current working directory. I attempted adding my current working directory in replacement for one of the `{}` but a similar error as above arises.

Comment: I have updated the post for clarity

Comment: No, sorry, but the regular expression `.csv` matches `acsv`, `bcsv`, `.csv`, `-csv` and anything else ending in `csv` because `.` in regular expressions (and not in shell globs which is what `-name` uses) means "any character". Try `touch notcsv` and then `find -regex './.*csv'`. That said, what you are asking for is not possible: you cannot have two files in the same directory with the same name, those would be the same file.

Comment: @terdon its probably because you're attempting a different approach to mine and thats what happens. Its why I used my current approach which does not have the issue you mention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141731/discussion-between-terdon-and-emil11).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two files in the same directory with the same name. That isn't possible since those would be the same file. The best you can do is make a backup copy with a different name. Also, your `-wholename`, isn't doing anything useful here, it is just ensuring that the file name contains a `.` but since you are looking for `-regex ./.*csv`, all results will start with `./` so all will match `.*`.

In addition, the regular expression `./*.csv` matches anything in the current directory whose name ends with `csv`, and not only files ending with `.csv`. To get only files ending with `.csv` with `-regex` you would need `-regex './.*\.csv`. But don't. Just use `-name`, it is simpler and easier. This command will find all files with a csv extension in the current directory and its subdirectories:

```
find . -name '*.csv'
```

Now, to make a backup copy of each file, keeping the same name, but giving it a `.csv.bak` extension, you can do:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec cp {} {}.bak \;
```

Comment: the `find` on my Mac does have `-wholename` "The same thing as -path, for GNU find compatibility.". Looks the same as the [FreeBSD one](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) wrt. that

Comment: Ah, thanks @ilkkachu, I looked at https://ss64.com/osx/find.html which didn't have it. In any case, `-wholename '.*'` is pointless when combined with `-regex './.*csv'`, right?

Comment: yeah, it looks like it doesn't do anything

Comment: Ah I see, so I was creating the same name. Therefore, I only have to update the name of the copied file

Comment: @Emil11 personally, I would create a directory called `csv_backups` and just copy everything there.

Comment: @terdon Sure! although this is all for experimental purpose. I wanted to work with a very messy directory with many duplicated files (because my directories somehow end up like this.) Therefore, I needed to know the copy tool, so I could do extra things like delete duplicates. But I would need to create copies with an index to denote a copy of the file is made. Exactly the same as Right-click > Copy. Will figure out

Comment: @Emil11 sorry, I don't know what "right click > copy" would do, I don't really use graphical file managers. But if you mean renaming `foo.csv` to `foo1.csv` that is quite possible as well. But we'd need a new question and an example of input to play with.

Comment: @terdon It was easier than expected, I have updated my post with how to achieve this. Although it append an extra dot, however, the following regex `.[^\.]*$` won't append the dot and give output like in your last comment. Do you know if there is a `find` alternative to this with `exec` ?

Comment: @Emil11 this is now a different question. Have a look around the site, there are many posts about incremental renaming although some won't work for macOS. If you don't find anything, post a new question. Make sure you show both the existing files _and_ how you want to rename them. Should they all get incremental numbers or only duplicates? You also need to clarify if your file names can contain spaces, newlines or other whitespace.